# Does Python have a linspace function in its std lib?

Tags: python, matlab

Does Python have a function like matlab's `linspace` in its standard library?

If not, is there an easy way to implement it without installing an external package?

Here's a quick and easy [definition of linspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) in matlab terms.

**Note**

I don't need a "vector result" as defined by the link, a list will do fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You can write your own (whicn isn't difficult), but if you are using Python to fulfil some of matlab's functionality then you definitely want to install `numpy`, which has `numpy.linspace`.

You may find [NumPy for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) informative.

Comment: FYI this link is dead.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to implement this is a generator function:

```
from __future__ import division

def linspace(start, stop, n):
    if n == 1:
        yield stop
        return
    h = (stop - start) / (n - 1)
    for i in range(n):
        yield start + h * i
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(linspace(1, 3, 5))
[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
```

That said, you should definitely consider using NumPy, which provides the `numpy.linspace()` function and lots of other features to conveniently work with numerical arrays.

Comment: Smallest of a teeniest nitpick: `linspace(a, b, 1)` gives a `ZeroDivisionError`, while matlab linspace would return `b`. Oh, and `n` defaults to 100.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Valid comment.  `numpy.linspace()` would return `a`, by the way.

Comment: From [the OP link](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html): *"For n < 2, linspace returns b."*. That *could* be wrong, of course. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I've noticed.  I just found it amusing that the NumPy analogue does the opposite. :)

Comment: Me, on the other hand, had not read your comment closely enough, and misread `numpy` for matlib. :-)

Comment: Another teeny nitpick: the last value of linspace(0, 1, 999) will not be exactly 1, because of normal numerical imprecision.  A quick fix is to make the for loop over range(n - 1), followed by `yield stop`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I'm aware of this and intentionally did not "fix" it.  Floating point numbers are inexact by there very nature, and I see no point in trying to pretend that some of them can be exact.

Answer (score 8):

You can define a function to do this:

```
def linspace(a, b, n=100):
    if n < 2:
        return b
    diff = (float(b) - a)/(n - 1)
    return [diff * i + a  for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Here too: `linspace(a, b, 1)` gives a `ZeroDivisionError`, while matlab linspace would return `b`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the spacing is > 1, this is the Python equivalent to the following MATLAB function call: `linspace(start,stop,spacing)`

```
start = 5
stop = 6
spacing = int(11)
linspace = [start + float(x)/(spacing-1)*(stop-start) for x in range(spacing)]
```

Comment: This does not seem quite right if `start` is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3 Solution using numpy

```py
import numpy as np
    
x1 = np.linspace(-3,3,11)
```

#### Solution Rewrite  using list comprehension

1. How do we get 11 linear spaced numbers btw -3 & 3 ?

   `x2 = [i for i in range(-5,6)]`
2. How do we scale these ints `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` down from -5 to 5 to  -3 to 3 ?

   ```
   i/(5/3) 
   x2 = [ i for i/(5/3) in range(-5,6)]
   print(x2)
   ```